# AttributeError while querying: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' has an attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, attributeerror

The following code:

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(r"sqlite:///" + r"d:\foo.db",
                       listeners=[ForeignKeysListener()])
Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
ses = Session()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foo"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique = True)

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("foo.id"))

    foo = relationship("Foo")


class FooBar(Base):
    __tablename__ = "foobar"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("bar.id"))

    bar = relationship("Bar")



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
ses.query(FooBar).filter(FooBar.bar.foo.name == "blah")
```

is giving me this error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with FooBar.bar has an attribute 'foo'
```

Any explanations, as to why this is happening, and guidance to how such a thing could be achieved?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

This is because you are trying to access `bar` from the `FooBar` class rather than a `FooBar` instance. The `FooBar` class does not have any `bar` objects associated with it--`bar` is just an sqlalchemy *InstrumentedAttribute*. This is why you get the error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with FooBar.bar has an attribute 'foo'
```

You will get the same error by typing `FooBar.bar.foo.name` outside the sqlalchemy query.

The solution is to call the `Foo` class directly:

```
ses.query(FooBar).join(Bar).join(Foo).filter(Foo.name == "blah")
```

Comment: What if the table has multiple relations to `Foo`?

Comment: That's true, but then we need to run `.join()` in every query of the app ( i.e: user id allowed/not allowed) - in that case, how can i "save" all these "join"s ?

Answer (score 40):

I cannot explain technically what happens but you can work around this problem by using:

```
ses.query(FooBar).join(Foobar.bar).join(Bar.foo).filter(Foo.name == "blah")
```

Comment: You can understand why it works in the documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins

Comment: This is correct, and the accepted answer is wrong because it does not join the tables on their foreign keys. You can actually remove the `.bar` and the `.foo` from this answer, and it still works.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error `Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' has an attribute`, but in my case, the problem was my model contained a Column named `query`, which was overwriting the internal property `model.query`.

I decided to rename that Column to `query_text` and that removed the error. Alternatively, passing the `name=` argument to the Column method would have worked: `query = db.Column(db.TEXT, name='query_text')`.

Answer (score 2):

A related error that can be caused by configuring your SQLAlchemy relationships incorrectly:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'Column' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'corresponding_column'
```

In my case, I incorrectly defined a relationship like this:

```
namespace   = relationship(PgNamespace, id_namespace, backref="classes")
```

The `id_namespace` argument to `relationship()` should just not be there at all. SQLAlchemy is trying to interpret it as an argument of a different type, and failing with an inscrutable error.

Comment: Thank you! A column and a relationship having the same name was causing this error and I didn't spot it until reading this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple working example with multiple relations to the same table. This generally avoid having the error `AttributeError while querying: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' has an attribute`

```py
def get_company(db: Session, company_id: int):
    best_contact = aliased(User, name="best_contact ")
    other_contact = aliased(User, name="other_contact")
        
    row = (
        db.query(Company, best_contact, other_contact)
        .join(best_contact, Company.best_contact_id == best_contact.id)
        .join(other_contact, Company.other_contact_id == other_contact.id)
        .filter(Company.id == company_id)
        .first()
    )
    return row
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stmt = (
   select(Bar.id).
   where(Bar.foo.has(Foo.name=="test"))
)
```

Maybe it will be useful... I found it here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#exists-forms-has-any