# How to order_by hybrid_property which is a column in relationship model?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to order some Parent objects when i do query by child_field.
I try to do it like this:

```py
stmt = select(Parent).where([<conditions>]).options([joinedload(Parent.child)]).order_by(desc(Parent.child_field)))
# I have more options in real code
```

while my models looks like these:

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __table_name___ = "parent"
    some_field = Column(String(256))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")])

    @hybrid_property
    def child_field(self):
        return self.child.child_field

class Child(base):
    child_field = Column(Integer)
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child")
```

I get error like this which discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589208/attributeerror-while-querying-neither-instrumentedattribute-object-nor-compa):

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Parent.child has an attribute 'child_field'
```

However solution I can't properly understand or it's not apply in my case.

So by [reading docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-custom-comparators) i concluded that I need to write custom comparator:

```py
class CustomComparator(Comparator):
    def operate(self, op, other, **kwargs):
        return op(self.__clause_element__(), other, **kwargs)
```

and added like this to parent model

```py
# --- snip ---
    @child_field.comparator
    def child_field(cls):
        return CustomComparator(cls.child_field)
```

But this implementation gives me recursion error of course.

Can anyone explain what's wrong and how to achieve my goal because apparently docs nor Comparator class insides does explain it me?
+
Should I even solve it with custom comparator when hybrid_property returns just an `int`?

UPD:
I tried use expression instead of comparator, and stopped getting comparator object related error, however query return not ordered list.

```py
# ---snip---
@child_field.expression
def child_filed(cls):
    return Child.child_field
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be working with an expression. Try to change your expression to the following :

```python
@child_field.expression
def child_field(cls):
    return cls.child.child_field
```

Full working example on MYSQL 8.0, SQLAlchemy 1.4.35, python 3.10

```python
# MODELS

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import desc


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # From the naming and your example, I assumed child is not a list
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent", uselist=False)

    @hybrid_property
    def child_field(self):
        return self.child.some_int

    @child_field.expression
    def child_field(cls):
        return Child.some_int


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    parent_id = Column(Integer)
    some_int = Column(Integer)

    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child")
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"))


# USAGE
engine = create_engine(
    "mysql://<user and host go here>/test_db?charset=utf8",
)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=conn))()

    child1 = Child()
    child1.some_int = 100
    child2 = Child()
    child2.some_int = 200

    parent1 = Parent()
    parent1.child = child1
    parent2 = Parent()
    parent2.child = child2


    session.add(parent1)
    session.add(parent2)
    session.commit()


    stmt = select(Parent, Child).join(Parent.child).order_by(desc(Parent.child_field))
    print(stmt)
    r = conn.execute(stmt)

    for row in r:
        print(row.values())

# OUTPUT
SELECT parent.id, child.id AS id_1, child.some_int, child.parent_id 
FROM parent JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id ORDER BY child.some_int DESC
[('id', 2), ('id_1', 2), ('some_int', 200), ('parent_id', 2)]
[('id', 1), ('id_1', 1), ('some_int', 100), ('parent_id', 1)]
```

EDIT : added a full working example

Comment: AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'child_field'

Comment: Added a working example, hope it helps.