# sqlalchemy EXCEPT: select all IDs except some ids

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to query my database with sqlalchemy in python to select all rows except those whose IDs belong to a certain list. Something like this;

```
exceptList = [1, 3, 5]
db.query.all() except those in exceptList
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Given this initial setup:

```py
class Question(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String)

db.create_all()

# Assign category alternately: id 1 ->, id 2 -> B etc.
db.session.add_all([Question(category='AB'[n % 2]) for n in range(5)])
db.session.commit()
```

Let's try to get question for category "A", assuming questions 1 - 3 have already been asked.

If you already have the list, you can do

```py
q = Question.query.filter(Question.id.not_in([1, 2, 3]), Question.category == 'A')
next_question = q.one()
print(next_question.id, next_question.category)
```

If the exception list must be obtained via a query, you can use an `EXCEPT` clause:

```py
# Create a filter than defines the rows to skip
skip = Question.query.filter(db.or_(Question.id < 4, Question.category == 'B'))
q = Question.query.except_(skip)
next_question = q.one()
print(next_question.id, next_question.category)
```

This [documentation section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/queryguide.html?highlight=union#selecting-entities-from-unions-and-other-set-operations) describes how to use `except_` (though it uses `UNION` as an example).

Comment: I got the following error when I tried the first code:

raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Question.id has an attribute 'not_in'

and this is my code:

nextQuestion = Question.query.filter_by(
            Question.id.not_in(previousQuestions), Question.category == category_id).one()
where previousquestions is the except list

Comment: It seems there may be something wrong with your models - for example see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16589208/5320906).  The code in the answer works - I've tested it twice.

Comment: I've modified the example to make it more like your code.  If you can't make it work you'll need to ask a new question and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

```
except_list = ["password", "another_column"]
result = session.query(*[c for c in User.__table__.c if c.name not in except_list).all()
```

Comment: I got the following error when I tried it:

    nextQuestion = Question.query(
TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable